# How sns can conditionally push message to different subscribers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm exploring ways to conditionally send message from sns to it's subscribers based on condition. The default sns publishes the message to all it's subscribers. I want to send it only based on certain conditions.
For example: sns has 2 subscribers one service and another sqs, now when the service is down i want to push it to sqs if the service is running I don't want to publish the message to sqs. Please let me know if there is any way to resolve this or any reference materials would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hello Shashank, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Are you doing it in any specific language or through AWS Console? Did you try re:pPost. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern. Could you be a little clearer in what you're trying to achieve? In the example you provided, the service should be consuming messages from SQS so that whether or not it's available, the messages are in a queue for processing.